# Mid-2012 Macbook Air doesn't always wake of from sleep running Arch Linux

Tags: hardware, sleep-wake, unix

My mid-2012 Macbook Air often powers off if the power cord is detached
while it is suspended, and sometimes, regardless of the cord, it doesn't
wake up from sleep.  I have had this problem since I installed Arch
Linux 3 years ago. 
Is there anything that might fix it?

Comment: You need to enable hibernation in Arch Linux. This hasn't really got much to do with Apple software, so I think you'll find better answers on how to do that in a Linux-based forum.

Comment: @jksoegaard? i didn't ask about hibernation.  power cord detached /= battery drained.

Comment: Well you stated that it sometimes does not wake up after sleep when the power cord is disconnected - sounded like you had an issue that hibernation could fix. If you know that this only happens when the battery has plenty of power left, then your problem is another thing...

Comment: @jksoegaard, yeah, i also do have hibernation.  pretty sure the problem is in the hardware; but, since it didn't exist under macos, it should be possible to fix it.